# Unity - Build runs slow while editor runs fine

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, build, editor, frame-rate

In the Unity editor my game runs fine at a near constant 60fps. However, when I build my game and run it as a standalone it runs incredibly slow at around 5-10fps. I have looked up this issue and so far the only solution I could find was to disable the Player Log from within Edit>ProjectSettings>Player. Since doing this the frame rate has increased a tiny amount however the game is still unplayable. I don't think it has anything to do with my code or graphics as, like I said, the game runs fine in the editor.

If anybody knows how I can fix this problem, in any way, it would be much appreciated if you could give a reply.

Kind Regards,

Tommy Eaves

Comment: Are you running the build and the editor at the same screen size and quality? The editor usually has lower resolution and quality than you get on a build. If you are running your build at 1920x1080 but your editor is only at 1024x768, it might be harder to run.

Comment: I have already tested this too. I expanded the game window in the editor to full screen and set the resolution to full 1080p but it still ran just fine.

Comment: Are we talking about "scene", "game" or both view when talking about the editor?

Comment: Both the game view and the scene view, as well as the inspector, the project window, the console and everything else.

Comment: In your _Build Settings_ window, make sure you don't have _Development Build_ checked

Comment: Also check *Quality Settings* the Editor *typically* uses a lower one than builds use.  Just check and make sure that the editor is set to the same one.

Comment: No that's not checked either.

Comment: I have defined my own quality settings and I have only made one level of quality so it must be running the same.

Comment: Actually you're right. It was a problem with the quality settings. I deleted my custom quality settings and reloaded the default and now it works. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Draco18s Would you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with my quality settings. I had set v-sync to its highest setting which was lagging the when built as a standalone but wasn't active while in the editor. I set my quality settings to the default settings and it all works now.